# How to use Wine?

Tags: windows, wine

I installed Wine from the Ubuntu Software Center, but I'm really not sure how to get my Windows applications to work.

I have Photoshop installed on a the Windows partition of my hard drive and I can see it in the Home Folder thing.  However, when I click on the Photoshop.exe file, nothing happens.  Am I doing something wrong?  Please help.

Comment: just find Photoshop in dash and click on that

Comment: I click on it in dash and it just opens up a terminal window for a split second, then closes.

Comment: Have you go to the actual wine website and check for any further steps on how you should run photoshop...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using normal wine program you can use PlayOnLinux to do this job.It is easy to use and it has more user friendly options than wine.PlayOnLinux is originally designed to run windows games on Linux but it can run programs like Adobe Photoshop too...

Answer (score 1):

When you installed Adobe Photoshop on Windows it added system files and registry entries.
These system files and registry entries are not present in Wine since you installed Photoshop on Windows not in Wine.

You need to install Photoshop on Wine.

Comment: ...or, if installation failed, copy the already installed files over from Windows. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.