# If I want to download a game, but it's only for windows, how do I download it?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89139/how-to-use-wine)

When I tried downloading this one game it said I need windows so is there a thing that will let me get it on Ubuntu?

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: "so is there a thing that will let me get it on Ubuntu?": See this answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/56057/15939

Comment: "how do I download it?" With Firefox?

Comment: does he mean that the website is not letting him download it? way more information is needed.